# Ricci curvature of a Kahler current

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact Kahler manifold, with a divisor $D$, $\mathcal{H}_{\omega} = \{\varphi \in C^{\infty}(M - D) \cap C^{0}(M)  : \omega_{\varphi} = \omega + \sqrt{-1} \partial \bar \partial \varphi > 0 \}$. We say a Kahler current $\omega_{KE}$ is called a Kahler-Einstein cone current with angle $2 \pi \beta$ along $D$ and Ricci curvature $\mu$ if $\omega_{KE} \in \mathcal{H}_{\omega}$, and if $Ric(\omega_{KE}) - (1-\beta)[D] = \mu \omega_{KE}$, where $[D]$ is the current of intergration along $[D]$. What is the formal definition of $Ric(\omega_{KE})$ as a current?

update: according to this [paper, page 9](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/alumni/2015-Chengjian-Yao.pdf), it should be understood in distributional sense. But given a smooth $(n-1, n-1)$ test form $\eta$, what is $\int_{M} Ric(\omega_{KE}) \wedge \eta$?

Comment: You need to assume that $\omega_{\rm KE}^n$ admits a density wrt a smooth volume form and that $f:=-\log \omega_{\rm KE}^n$ is locally integrable on $M$. The latter condition is legit thanks to the former condition. Then you define $\mathrm{Ric}(\omega_{\rm KE}):=i\partial \bar\partial f$.

Comment: I know that $\omega_{KE}^n$ is well defined if we assume that its potential is bounded, but the output will be a distribution. How do you take the log of that? Can you add in more details?

Comment: More specifically the output of the monge-ampere operator will be a randon measure.

Comment: You need to *assume* that the MA measure admits a density wrt Lebesgue. In your context, $\omega_{\rm KE}$ is actually defined as a solution of a Monge-Ampère equation whose RHS has a density wrt Lebesgue whose $\log$ is in $L^1$. So you can apply the definition I mentioned earlier.